# Menu drop down which does not use item id as default?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, joomla

I have a form in Joomla which has a drop down menu with a number of items to select. The problem is that if the form is saved and someone chooses not to choose one of the items (not mandatory), then the first item in the list on this menu is selected by default. Now I could I guess in the backend create a new blank item with no name and give it the id=1 to show as first in the list but was wondering if there was another way. The current code is:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="componentskey">
      <label for="items_id"> <?php echo JText::_( 'ITEMS' ); ?></label>
    </td>
    <td>
     <select name="items_id" id="items_id">
      <?php echo ItemsHelper::show_items_tree($this->items,0, $this->item->items_id); ?>
     </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

EDIT: Ok the function is

Ok the function is

```
function show_items_tree($items,$level, $selected_items_id)
{
   $return = "" ;

   for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++)
   {
       $return .= ItemsHelper::render_option($items[$i]->id,$items[$i]->item_name,$level, $selected_items_id);
       $level ++;
       if(!empty($items[$i]->sons))
       {
           $return .=  ItemsHelper::show_items_tree($items[$i]->sons,$level, $selected_items_id);
        }
        $level --;
    }
   //echo $return;
   return $return;
```

Comment: Can you post this php function here `show_items_tree()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you definitely need to add an empty option to start with:

```
<option value="">- Select something -</option>
```

as the first option, you could insert it directly in the html markup right after the `<select>` start tag.